# XML parsing of a .txt file printing nothing on the console

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, text-files

This is the first time I try to parse `XML` so be gentle with me :).

So i downloaded the source code of a web page i want to parse certain information from http://www.songlyrics.com/eminem/my-name-is-lyrics/.

Now i copy pasted the `XML` file to the notepad.
I saved the file as `XML - 1`.

**My code looks like this:**

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Program starts:");

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("C:/Users/volca_000/Desktop/XML - 1.txt"));
            NodeList paragraphsNodeList =  document.getElementsByTagName("p");

            for (int i = 0;i < paragraphsNodeList.getLength();i++)
            {
                Node paragraphNode = paragraphsNodeList.item(i);
                if (paragraphNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                {
                    Element element = (Element)paragraphNode;
                    String node = element.getTextContent();
                    System.out.println(node);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // End of main
} // End of Program class
```

Even if i discard the `if` statement get nothing on the console.

```
if (paragraphNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
```

What am i doing wrong? Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: A quick look at the source code of that page (assuming you can parse it as XML) suggests that the paragraph elements don't have text content, but rather other elements such as hyperlinks etc. Does the above code successfully find a sequence of paragraph elements ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Actually i checked to see if `NodeList paragraphsNodeList =  document.getElementsByTagName("p");` paragraphsNodeList is not null and either case it prints nothing. Some weird thing. And some execution of the program catch Exceptions and some does not.

Comment: @BrianAgnew And BTW , why you assume i can't parse it as `XML`? If not , So what is the method for doing what I'm trying to do? (Get the lyrics on my console screen).

Comment: @sgpalit I will check that out.